# How can Angular URLs be made cleaner by removing the "#"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a website that currently has a URL like this

```
http://www.bruxzir.com/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/
```

I am evaluating angular and have so far begun the app with [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). But now I have URLs that look like this

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html#/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/
```

I have used meteor for a SPA and that had compatible URL structure. So how can I do this with Angular? basically get rid of the `index.html#` from the URL. Here is my code.

**index.html** - The link in the header

```
<li><a href="#/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/">Cases</a></li>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'home'});
  $routeProvider.when('/features-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/features.html', controller: 'features'});
  $routeProvider.when('/science-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/science.html', controller: 'science'});
  $routeProvider.when('/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/videos.html', controller: 'videos'});
  $routeProvider.when('/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/cases.html', controller: 'cases'});
  $routeProvider.when('/testimonials-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/testimonials.html', controller: 'testimonials'});
  $routeProvider.when('/authorized-bruxzir-labs-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/labs.html', controller: 'labs'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [HTML5 mode](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) provided by `$locationProvider`:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  //adding this line
  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'home'});
  $routeProvider.when('/features-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/features.html', controller: 'features'});
  $routeProvider.when('/science-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/science.html', controller: 'science'});
  $routeProvider.when('/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/videos.html', controller: 'videos'});
  $routeProvider.when('/cases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/cases.html', controller: 'cases'});
  $routeProvider.when('/testimonials-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/testimonials.html', controller: 'testimonials'});
  $routeProvider.when('/authorized-bruxzir-labs-zirconia-dental-crown/', {templateUrl: 'partials/labs.html', controller: 'labs'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Comment: This worked after I also removed the `#` from the links in my `index.html` file. otherwise the URL looked like this `/home#%2Fcases-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown%2F` . I was also reading that to make the site crawlable i needed to add `<meta name="fragment" content="!" />` in the head. am I missing anyhing to not hurt the SEO?

Comment: Sorry, I don't focus yet on specific Angular's need for SEO part.